# SQL - Join multiple rows to a table and transpose into columns

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery

So I've got two tables as below:

Opportunity:

| Opp ID | Opp Name | Opp Owner |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Opp 1 | Gary |
| 02 | Opp 2 | Trevor |

Opportunity Split:

| Opp ID | Owner | Split % |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Gary | 100% |
| 02 | Trevor | 50% |
| 02 | Peter | 50% |

SO I then want to be able to put the split into the first table like

| Opp ID | Opp Name | Opp Owner | First Owner | First Owner Split | Second Owner | Second Owner Split |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Opp 1 | Gary | Gary | 100% | null | null |
| 02 | Opp 2 | Trevor | Trevor | 50% | Peter | 50% |

I'm awful with SQL so any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select *, 
    row_number() over(partition by Opp_ID order by Split desc) pos
  from table_1 
  left join table_2 
  using (Opp_ID)
) pivot (
  min(Owner) as Owner, min(Split) as Split for pos in (1,2,3)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]